# Como popular um base de dados SQLite através de um arquivo .sql?

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript

Tenho um arquivo `.sql` e preciso executar todas as linhas, inserir todos os registros que estão nele, em uma tabela dentro do SQLite.

Conteúdo do arquivo `mydb.sql`:

```
CREATE TABLE tblVeiculo (VeiculoId INT, Codigo [TEXT(9)], Fabricante [TEXT(255)], Modelo [TEXT(255)], AnoInicial INT, AnoFinal INT, Portas INT, Combustivel [VARCHAR(30)], NrMotorObstruido BOOLEAN);
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES (1, '001034066', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 SB(E-TRONIC)(URB.) DIES 2P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 2, 'DIES', 1);
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES (2, '001034078', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(RODOV.) DIES 1P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 1, 'DIES', 0);
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES (3, '001034080', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(RODOV.C/AR) DIES 1P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 1, 'DIES', 0);
INSERT INTO tblVeiculo (VeiculoId, Codigo, Fabricante, Modelo, AnoInicial, AnoFinal, Portas, Combustivel, NrMotorObstruido) VALUES (4, '001034091', 'AGRALE', 'MT 12.0 4X2 LE(E-TRONIC)(URBANO) DIES 2P BASICO', 2005, 2013, 2, 'DIES', 0);

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
```

Como posso popular uma base de dados SQLite através de um arquivo `.sql`??

Answer (score 0):

Eu não entendo de *TypeScript*, mas creio que ele seja uma linguagem que seja convertida em JavaScript posteriormente (me corrija se eu estiver enganado), então você pode usar as APIs nativas como `FileReader` ou `XMLHttpRequest`, se estiver usando cordova então pode fazer algo assim:

```
function CarregarArquivo(arquivo, callback, errorCallback)
{
    var type = LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT;
    var size = 5*1024*1024;

    window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback);

    function successCallback(fs)
    {
        fs.root.getFile(arquivo, {}, function(fileEntry)
        {
            fileEntry.file(function(file)
            {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                    callback(this.result);
                };

                reader.readAsText(file);

            }, errorCallback);
        }, errorCallback);
    }
}

CarregarArquivo('file.sql', function(fullquery) {
     //Aqui pode usar o split para separar por `;`
     var queries = fullquery.split(';');

     for (var i = 0, queries.length; i < j; i++) {
         //algo como executeQuery(queries[i].trim());
     }
}, function(erro) {
    alert(erro);
});
```

Se vier de um arquivo selecionado via input pode usar algo como:

```
function executeQueries(fullquery) {
     //Aqui pode usar o split para separar por `;`
     var queries = fullquery.split(';');

     for (var i = 0, queries.length; i < j; i++) {
         //algo como executeQuery(queries[i].trim());
     }
}

//Selecione o elemento do <input type="file" id="sqlfile">
document.getElementById("sqlfile").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
     readFile(evt.target.files[0], executeQueries); //Mesma função
}, false);
```